# ios p12 odd behavior

Tags: ios, aws-iot

I've an odd behavior with p12 certificates and amazon iot.

If i include a p12 file in the project ide, and connect to aws iot, every thing works fine

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *resource = [bundle pathForResource:nil ofType:@"p12"];
certificate = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:resource];
[self continueConnect:certificate];
```

but if i download the certificate from the server and save into a local file

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/certificate.p12"];
certificate = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:appFile];
[self continueConnect:certificate];
```

I get the following error: CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9829)

I've checked in a for loop that both certificates are indentical

any tip?

Comment: Have you made sure you use the certificate only once (fully) downloaded? I.e. isn’t it just an async issue? Just log the certificate contents and size when you use it to be sure...

Comment: I've downloaded the certificate, write locally and restart the app. I've also compare the 2 certificates in a for loop byte by byte

Comment: Did you do the comparison within the code above, or separately? Have you checked that the certificate is actually correctly loaded?